# How can I write a script that allows the user to enter input for it to run

Tags: linux, scripting

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo add-apt-repository
echo -n "Enter ppa here > "
read $response

sudo apt-get update
    if [ "W: GPG error: * NO_PUBKEY" = "0" ]; then
        echo "Enter the 16 digit key provided at the end of this error."
sudo apt-add adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key
    echo -n "Enter key here > "
    read text
        else
            echo "Update succeeded with no errors."
    fi
sudo apt-get update
```

But the script stops because no args after repository. How can the user get prompted to enter the repo?

Comment: can't say why it is stopping with no-args, but you realize that your statement `if [ "W: GPG error: * NO_PUBKEY" = "0" ]; then` will always return `false` and execute the `else` statement, yes? Also, do you mean it stops after the first cmd in your script (`sudo add-apt-repository`) ? Is your `sudo` setup correctly? For any of these items, please improve the evidence presented in your Q, rather that engaging in a long discussion in comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error: need a repository as argument
Enter ppa here! >
I enter a ppa but it continues to update without adding ppa.

Comment: Error: need a repository as argument
Enter ppa here! >
I enter a ppa but it continues to update without adding ppa.